# Set up MySQL behind a proxy server

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am deploying a MySQL server behind a proxy server (apache mod_proxy). I am getting this error when I try to connect using mysql client or using php to connect to mysql server.

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

I tried by setting bind-address to 0.0.0.0 and commenting it, but noting worked.

I am doing some port mapping on proxy server in addition to proxying, using proxypass.
eg:

```
ProxyPass / 123.145.1.5:13306
ProxyPassReverse / http://123.145.1.5:13306
```

I have set the apache server to listen to 3306 and there is no mysql server running on proxy server.

Comment: From your config it looks like your trying to talk HTTP to MySQL. Is that right? Can mod_proxy go in front of MySQL?

Comment: Well when it comes to remote logging to mysql-server it uses HTTP right? (Please correct me if I wrong)

Comment: Nope, HTTP isn't used by MySQL. If you're looking to simply proxy a mysql connection you may find this easier: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy

Comment: Oops. A BIG Thank for saving me. I thought I could do it using mod_proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make this clear, mod_proxy is for HTTP protocol only. It reads headers from HTTP protocol to work.

You should try with iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to 123.145.1.5:13306
```