# How to setup mysql server behind a proxy server

Tags: mysql, apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am deploying a mysql server behind a proxy server (apache mod_proxy). I am getting this error when I try to connect using mysql client

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

I tried both commenting and puting 0.0.0.0 in mysql my.cnf noting is worked.

Comment: Is it related to programming?

Comment: I might be mistaking but is the proxy mod of apache not limited to http/https protocol? Would it not require a proper proxy installation?

Comment: @Shakti Singh It relate when it comes to setup a connection in php.(mysql_connect). it gives the same error

Comment: @cularis sorry I'll put there also

Comment: @gihan: It is all about **configure mysql server behind a proxy server** nothing else

Comment: @Zenklys I am using this because I am doing some port mapping also. I forward requests comes port 3306 in proxy to another port in mysql server which runs behind the proxy

Comment: @Shakti Singh Please give me some example of how to configure the mysql server. Your answer is highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment above seems confirmed by [your post on server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/282502/set-up-mysql-server-behind-a-proxy-server)
You cannot use the apache mod_proxy to "proxy" a mysql server.